# create new column of values against an existing string in a csv file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, file-io

I have a program to store a persons name and their score, in a csv file in python.

for example this is my current code :

```
student_name = input("Name: ")
score = input("Score: ")

class_name = "student_scores.csv" 

file = open(class_name , 'a') 
file.write(str(student_name)  + ", " + str(score) + "\n") 
file.close()
```

The output csv file is, (name = bob) and (score = 1) :

```
bob, 1
```

When i enter another score (2) for the same person (bob) the csv file looks like this:

```
bob, 1
bob, 2
```

However how can i change my code, so that the csv file looks like this (with more than 2 columns) :

```
bob, 1, 2
```

Comment: You have to read the data from the old file, figure out what the contents of the new file will be, and overwrite the file.

Comment: Out of curiosity where is this coming from? I see questions about this assignment extremely often.

Comment: Why have you created a near identical question to your last question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first things first, it is simpler to use the `csv` library to manipulate a csv file. All you need to do is read the csv file into a list called `data` using list comprehension or iteration. Here, the `data` is a list of lists with the inner lists representing the rows of the csv file. Now check the `student_name` with every first element of each inner list. If it matches append the `score` to that inner list and write the contents of `data` to the csv file. If it doesn't match write a list with the `student_name` and `score` to the csv file in append mode.

```
import csv

student_name = input("Name: ")
score = input("Score: ")

with open("student_scores.csv", "r") as f:
    data = [item for item in csv.reader(f)]

for item in data:
    if item[0] == student_name :
        item.append(score)
        with open("student_scores.csv", 'w') as f:
            csv.writer(f).writerows(data)
        break
else:
    with open("student_scores.csv", 'a') as f:
        csv.writer(f).writerow([student_name, score])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: just wondering, is there anyway to do it with the csv module? If not then this code doesn't seem to work for me, so could you please help

Comment: yeah, you are right. I posted the answer without verifying it. There were minor changes that needed to be done like changing the file opening mode from binary to text and corrected the indentation of `break`. Now i have made the necessary changes to make it work and i have verified it by running. Thank you for pointing it out.